# C Programming; GCC crashes while running

Tags: c, gcc, crash

um hello, well I tried to compile my code and it works fine, then run it, at first its working, until I input a character it suddenly crash. Do you know whats wrong with it? BTW Im just a beginner in programming so any suggestions or criticize is welcome. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char w;
    int a, b;
    float cola, change, rb, pep;

printf("Welcome! Please choose your drink from these beverages! Press the following buttons to order; \nA - Cola \nB - Root Beer \nC - Pepsi \n");
scanf("%c", w );

if(w=='A'){
    printf("\nYou chose Cola!\n This cost $0.75.\n How many would you like to buy?");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    cola=a*.75;
        printf("\nYou bought %d cola/colas. That will be %f. How much is your money?/n", a,cola);
        scanf("%d", b);
    change=b-cola;
        printf("\nYour change is %f.\n Please come again!\n", change);
}

else if(w=='B'){
    printf("\nYou chose Root Beer!\n This cost $1.00.\n How many would you like to buy?");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    rb=a*1.00;
        printf("\nYou bought %d root beer/beers. That will be %f. How much is your money?/n", a,rb);
        scanf("%d", b);
    change=b-rb;
        printf("\nYour change is %f.\n Please come again!\n", change);
}
else if(w == 'C'){
    printf("\nYou chose Pepsi!\n This cost $1.50.\n How many would you like to buy?");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    pep=a*1.50;
        printf("\nYou bought %d pepsi/s. That will be %f. How much is your money?/n", a,pep);
        scanf("%d", b);
    change=b-pep;
        printf("\nYour change is %f.\n Please come again!\n", change);
}
else{printf("Please come again./n");}





return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not a good title. `gcc` doesn't "run" your code and, therefore, `gcc` doesn't crash. `gcc` compiler your code, and then it sounds like your code crashes under certain conditions.

Comment: `scanf("%d", b);` should be `scanf("%d", &b);`, that's probably what's crashing your program.

Comment: `scanf` requires that you give it the *address* of the thing you want to read. See the manual page for `scanf`.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for pointing it out, i tried replacing them but it still crashes, any other ideas?

Comment: @llawliet_78 Did you replace all three instances of the mistake? Notice that `scanf("%c", w );` should be `scanf("%c", &w );` as well.

Comment: @Daniel omg! Thank You! Its fine now!! Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

These lines:

```
scanf("%d", b);
scanf("%c", w );
```

will crash. You need to pass a pointers to `b` and `w` instead:

```
scanf("%d", &b);
scanf("%c", &w );
```

Answer (score 1):

The scanf function takes an address in memory as argument, in other words your input value needs a place in memory to store and for that you need to give an address,
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm here will explain more about it.

Suggestion:If you will continue programming in your life, you should start naming the variables better, for example in your case : a should be numberOfDrinks and b should be moneyAmount or something similar, you will see when you will be working on a bigger project how important this is

Suggestion/Tip:You should start learning how to work in a modular way, meaning you should use functions , because it's best practice and you can reuse the code as many times as you like in the program, and it's easier to test also.